# Element type is invalid : expected a string or class/function but got:undefined ,check render method of Home

Tags: react-native

I am creating an app in ReactNative and i got this issue. Following are the files containing code

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import Home from 'MobileApp/src/users/Home';
AppRegistry.registerComponent('MobileApp', () => App);
```

**Home.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { View,Button} from 'react-native';
import Profile from './Profile';

class Home extends Component{
  onPressProfile(){ 
    navigate('Profile', { name: 'Profile' })
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
        <View style={styles.buttonStyle}>
          <Button
            onPress={this.onPressProfile}
            title="Profile"         
          />  
        </View>     
      </View>
    );  
  }
}

const styles= {
  viewStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
};
export default  Home;
```

Error is in my Home.js. what is the mistake?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the error screen? Also, the code seems to be missing quite a few pieces. It will be better if you provide some what complete code to avoid confusions.

Comment: what is `navigate` in `onPressProfile()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `index.js` file, you should be using your `Home` component as entry point of your app.

**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import Home from 'MobileApp/src/users/Home';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MobileApp', () => Home);
```

In your actual code, `App` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You may have error on this line:

```
navigate('Profile', { name: 'Profile' })
```

need to define navigate to access it. Assuming you are learning from official [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html)

```
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
```

And import navigation would be like:

```
import {
  StackNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';

const App = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
});
```

For further information how navigation works, [check documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/)